# TypeGraphQL createUnionFunction with parameter

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I'm trying to implement an extension of **typegraphql**'s `createUnionType()` function to where I can pass in a class/ObjectType instead of hardcoding, and it will return a union type of both.

What I have so far doesn't work but I feel like it's possible. Could anyone provide any insight? Maybe it's not possible?

**typedefs**

```js
import { ObjectType, Field, createUnionType, ClassType } from "type-graphql";

@ObjectType()
export default class MutationSuccess {

    @Field()
    success: boolean = true;

}

// Doesn't work
export const MutationResponse = (objectType: ClassType) => createUnionType({
    name: 'MutationResponseType',
    types: () => [MutationSuccess, objectType],
})
```

**How I'm trying to use it in my resolver**

```js
@Resolver()
export default class RelationResolver {

    @Mutation(() => MutationResponse(Relation), { description: 'follow user' })
    async follow(
        @Arg('relationInput') relationInput: RelationInput
    ): Promise<Relation | MutationSuccess> {
        // do some stuff
    }

}
```

**error**

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for follow
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Relation` class need to be decorated with `@ObjectType` and the union type name has to be unique.